# Appropriate technique for comparing two experiments with replicates

Tags: t-test

I have an experiment where I take a set of samples, and test them. If I then take a second set of samples and repeat the experiment, how can I test if there is a significant difference between the sample sets?

More specifically, I take 25 rods of a material and subject them to a breakage test at five different strain rates, with five replicates per strain rate. I can plot breakage stress vs strain rate as a scatter plot and calculate the standard errors, etc.

Now if I take different 25 rods of a treated material and repeat the experiment under the same conditions and same strain rates I get a second scatter plot.

I know from other work that the breakage stress at a each strain rate is (almost!) normally distributed.

How can I tell if there is a difference due to the treatment?

I could take each strain rate separately and do a (paired?) t-test giving 5 p-values or just put all the 25 results together for untreated and treated, then do a two sample t-test but either of these seem to be ignoring the structure of the data.